# How to check if an mqtt output node is receiving messages for every certain period of time in node red

Tags: node-red

in my node-red flow , i have a mqtt output node that is subscribing to a topic .Actually for every 5 seconds a message is being published to that toipc from other client.my intension is  to check if the message is not arrived for every 5 seconds ,then trigger an event . is there any node that checks if an mqtt node is getting message for every certain period of time

Answer (score 1):

<del>I can't think of any built-in node that does that.</del> You can use the trigger node that does just that as @hardillb pointed it out in his answer.

One workaround could have been:

- Have a [global context variable](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions) set to true every time the MQTT  node receives a message
- Have an inject node triggered every 5 seconds (can be configured in the repeat section of the node) that checks if the global variable value is true

  - if yes then sets it back to false
  - if no raises an error saying the message wasn't received

Comment: check @hardillb answer below, there was in fact a built-in node

Answer (score 1):

The core Trigger node can be reset by a new incoming message and will only send it's timeout if a new message does not arrive after that time.

[image]